# IBM Worklight 6.1: Authenticated Push for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

The only official resource available for authenticated push notification on windows phone 8 is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941099(v=vs.105).aspx but it doesn't meets the requirement. Can someone list the steps for authenticated push notifications on windows phone 8 using IBM Worklight 6.1. 
[image: application-descriptor.xml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [IBM Worklight user documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_WP8.html):

> To use an authenticated push notification service, you must first set
>   up a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate keystore. For more
>   information, [see SSL certificate keystore setup](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_ssl_certificate_keystore_setup.html). The keystore can
>   contain several certificates, one of which is the certificate for
>   authenticated push notifications to Microsoft Push Notification
>   Service (MPNS).
>
> You must also authenticate your web service with Microsoft, as documented in the Windows Phone > Development Center at http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/develop/.
>
> The `serviceName` attribute from the application descriptor is passed to
>   the application's client side, and is used when a new notification
>   channel is created. The URI token of the notification channel starts
>   with "https", rather than "http".
>
> The `keyAlias` and `keyAliasPassword`
>   attributes are used by Worklight® Server to extract the certificate
>   from the Java™ keystore file, so that it can be used in the handshake
>   process with Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS). Any push
>   notifications submitted to the application will be authenticated and
>   secure.

The end result should look something like this:

```
<windowsPhone8>
  <pushSender>
    <authenticatedPush serviceName="myservice"
                       keyAlias="janedoe"
                       keyAliasPassword="a1b2c3d4"</authenticatedPush>
  </pushSender>
...
</windowsPhone8>
```

There is nothing else to it.
If you are encountering issues, you should probably actually note those in the question body.